# Double-hearing everything in Gangland

Tags: gangland

So I bought Gangland, and after the game starts, I hear every sound, music, everything twice. It's really, really annoying.

Have any of you met with such a problem? Any idea how to fix this?
(Besides contacting GOG support, that is).

Comment: Have you tried applying the patch update?

Comment: @Mugen - It's the latest version, at least that's what GOG said. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem.  Right click on the shortcut, go to "Properties" and then "Compatability".  For some reason GOG has it preset to run in compatability for Win98/Me...

When I switched compatability mode **off** it worked fine!